# How to send a base64 image to the server without damage

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the function to send the data to the server. I need to send the data, including the image, when sending the data attached the image, appears error, and the image arrive to the server is corrupted, and when the data is sent without it does not occur any error

this is my code:

```
func Register() {
        let Name = FullName.text
        let Phone = Phone_Num.text
        let Password = self.Password.text
        let Board = Board_Num.text
        let Details = Car_Type.text! + " " + Car_Brand.text! + " " + Car_Model.text!
        let CarImage:UIImage = Car_Image.image!
        if let dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(CarImage, 0.5)?.base64EncodedString() {
            let fullBase64String = "data:image/png;base64,\(dataImage))"
            let url = "someURL"
            let parameter = ["driver_name": Name!, "phone_number": Phone!, "card_number": Password!, "board_number": Board!, "car_details": Details, "car_image": "\(fullBase64String)"]
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request as Any)
                print(response.response as Any)
                print(response.result as Any)
                print(response.result.value as Any)
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                    let Status = json["Status"].stringValue
                    if Status == "Success" {
                        self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.alert(errormessage: "Done")
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch {
                    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the error:

> [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2868 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library

Comment: This likely means that the server hung up on you. You need to look at what data you actually send to the server (I mean the actual bytes that you put on the network), and how the server responds to that.

Comment: This is particularly strange: `"\(fullBase64String)"`. If that isn't exactly equivalent to `fullBase64String`, then you've likely done something wrong here.

Comment: does this error appear on the server side or the client (your iOS app) side?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann on the client side